# Unit test service method called from an anonymous component controller function in Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

After 3 days of research I'm trying to put the pieces of the puzzle together but with no success. I'm trying to unit test a component's controller and be sure the service injected to it assigns the data to an array.

my component is:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

  app.controller('MealSuggestionsController', MealSuggestionsController);

  MealSuggestionsController.$inject = ['MealSuggestionsService'];

  function MealSuggestionsController (MealSuggestionsService) {

    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.meals = [];

    function main () {
      MealSuggestionsService.getMeals().then(
        function (response) {
          if (!response) {
            return;
          }
          ctrl.meals = response.meals;
        }
      );
    }

    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
      main();
    };
  }

  app.component('mealSuggestions', {
    transclude: true,
    controller: 'MealSuggestionsController',
  });

})();
```

I want to test that ctrl.meals array will be correctly filled with data so I write the following test:

```
describe("MealSuggestionsController", function() {
  var $componentController, $rootScope, MealSuggestionsService, MealSuggestionsController, scope;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('wwwAPP');

    // Provide will help us create fake implementations for our dependencies
    module(function($provide) {

    // Fake MealSuggestionsService Implementation returning a promise
      $provide.value('MealSuggestionsService', {
        getMeals: function() {
          return {
            then: function(callback) {
              return callback([
                {
                  "foo": "bar"
                }
              ]);
            }
          };
        }
      });
      return null;
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function() {

    // When Angular Injects the MealSuggestionsService dependency,
    // it will use the implementation we provided above
    inject(function($injector) {
      $componentController = $injector.get('$componentController');
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      MealSuggestionsService = $injector.get('MealSuggestionsService');
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      MealSuggestionsController = $componentController ('mealSuggestions', {
        $scope: {},
        MealSuggestionsService: MealSuggestionsService
      })
    });
    main = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function() {
      MealSuggestionsService.getMeals();
    });
  });

  it('The MealSuggestionsController should be defined', function() {
    expect(MealSuggestionsController).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('main() should be a defined function', function() {
    expect(main).toBeDefined();
    expect(typeof main).toEqual("function");
  });

  it('should have call main', function() {
    spyOn(MealSuggestionsController, 'main').and.callThrough();
    expect(MealSuggestionsController.main).toHaveBeenCalled();
    spyOn(MealSuggestionsService, 'getMeals').and.callThrough();
    expect(MealSuggestionsService.getMeals).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I cannot make main call MealSuggestionsService.getMeals and check for assigned data.

Comment: please go through https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: `main` is local function. Not a method. There's no `MealSuggestionsController.main`. You can't mock it - and you shouldn't. Just call `MealSuggestionsController.$onInit()` (it isn't called automatically when a controller is instantiated with $componentController) *after* you set up a spy on `MealSuggestionsService.getMeals`. And `MealSuggestionsService` should be mocked totally in controller test.